# Can pyzmq publishers be operated from class instances?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have following code for a Publisher, which instantiates a few class instances and publishes some messages.

However, I don't receive anything at Subscriber side.

**Publisher**

```
import zmq
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class SendData:
    def __init__(self, msg, port):
        self.msg = msg
        self.port = port
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self.sock.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:'+str(self.port))
        time.sleep(1)

    def sender(self):
        self.sock.send_json(self.msg)

def main():
    for device, port in zip(['2.2.2.2', '5.5.5.5'],[5001, 5002]):
        msg = {device:'Some random message'}
        instance = SendData(device, port)
        Process(target=instance.sender).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Subscriber**

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
recv_sock1 = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
recv_sock1.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5001')
recv_sock1.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

recv_sock2 = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
recv_sock2.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5002')
recv_sock2.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

while True:
    if recv_sock1.poll(10):
        msg = recv_sock1.recv_json()
        print msg

    if recv_sock2.poll(10):
        msg = recv_sock2.recv_json()
        print msg
```

I had subscribers started before publishers could publish anything. Also, I can see TCP connections are in Established so connections are made.

- pyzmq version 16.0.0
- python version 2.7

**Q1:** Are 0mq publishers supported from class instances?
**Q2:** What am I missing?

Comment: I just had a quick look at your code, but first thing I noticed was the use of multiple processes. You are instantiating an object in the main process and run a worker process that calls that object's bound method `sender`, which in turn tries to access the zeromq socket created in the main process. I'm almost certain that this won't work. You have to access the socket in the same process you opened it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So what's a good way to bind sockets in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A1: Yes, they are.

### A2: Conflicts of scope-of-use v/s Zero-sharing, one of ZeroMQ maxims

Once your original **Publisher** code is being executed in `main()`, the class instantiation process creates ( i.e. inside the `main()`-process scope-of-use ), via the `.__init__()` constructor-method, it's own **`Context()`** -instance, which thus belongs ( incl. all of it's derived child-objects ( sockets et al ) ) to this **`main()`**-process.

Next, the call to the **`Process(...)`** initiates another few processes, that receive the class-instances ( the pity is that these have already created ZeroMQ non-shareable toys ) from the `main()`-scope-of-use.

## Solution?

A possible dirty quick hack could be to defer the ZeroMQ **`Context()`** instantiation -- yes, just move it from `.__init__()` to some **`.aDeferredSETUP()`** that will be executed specifically under different scope-of-use inside each of the spinned-of `Process()`-process, different from `main()`-process and you ought be done, as Zero-sharing is safely obeyed.

```
class SendData:
    def __init__(self, msg, port):
        self.msg      = msg
        self.port     = port

        self.NotSETUP = True
        self.ctx      = None
        self.sock     = None
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ L8R
        # ctx         = zmq.Context()
        # self.sock   = ctx.socket( zmq.PUB )
        # self.sock.bind( 'tcp://127.0.0.1:' + str( self.port ) )
        # time.sleep( 1 )
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ L8R

    def sender( self ):
        if      self.NotSETUP:
                self.aDeferredSETUP()
        
        self.sock.send_json( self.msg )

    def aDeferredSETUP( self ):     # create I/O-threads in Process(), not main()
        self.ctx    = zmq.Context() 
        self.sock   = self.ctx.socket( zmq.PUB )
        self.sock.bind( 'tcp://127.0.0.1:' + str( self.port ) )
        time.sleep( 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

As was said before, trying to share the ZeroMQ context between processes is the problem here and the solution by *user3666197* will work.
However, I would suggest subclassing `multiprocessing.Process` in this case. That way, it is much clearer what part of the code is executed in which process. It also makes your code more readable and reusable.

The following code creates one sender process per device. The sender processes can be reused during the runtime of your program to send more data:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import zmq
import time

class Sender(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, port):
        super(Sender, self).__init__()
        self._port = port
        self._messages = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self._do_stop = multiprocesing.Event()

    def run(self):
        """
        This code is executed in a new process.
        """
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
        sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:" + str(self._port))
        while not self._do_stop.is_set():
            try:
                msg = self._message.get_nowait()
                sock.send_json(msg)
            except queue.Empty:
                time.sleep(0.01)

    def stop(self):
        self._do_stop.set()

    def send_message(self, msg):
        self._messages.put(msg)

def main():
    data = zip(['2.2.2.2', '5.5.5.5'], [5001, 5002])
    # create senders
    senders = {device: Sender(port) for device, port in data}
    # start senders
    for device in senders:
        senders[device].start()
    # send messages
    for device, port in zip(['2.2.2.2', '5.5.5.5'],[5001, 5002]):
        msg = {device: 'Some random message'}
        senders[device].send_message(msg)
    # do more stuff here....
    # ... e.g. send more messages
    # ...
    # once you are finished, stop the subprocesses
    for device in senders:
        senders[device].stop()
```

I hope this helps solving your problem.